# USB Ethernet adapter disconnecting on Windows 11 and DELL Inspiron 5370 2-in-1

Tags: usb, windows-11, usb-network-adapter

The model "DELL Inspiron 5379 2-in-1" does not officially support Windows 11. However, I upgraded anyway, and the result is so far, so good in most parts.

However, the USB Ethernet adapter is getting disconnected once in a while. Usually, the adapter can reconnect after a few seconds.

I checked the "Event Viewer," and I noticed a coincidence happening at the same time in the context of "Windows Logs > Security": at the time of disconnect, the system log recorded several "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" events in less than one second. So I wonder what the "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" events mean in this situation.

The WiFi works OK but is slower than the cabled Ethernet, so I still want to try fixing the USB Ethernet adapter.

I will highly appreciate any hints and suggestions, and please let me know if you need any more details.

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          3/21/2023 7:13:11 PM
Event ID:      4798
Task Category: User Account Management
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      -computer-name-
Description:
A user's local group membership was enumerated.

... many others ...
```

Comment: Perhaps setting GPO for security audit might help, https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/book/page.aspx?spid=chapter2

Comment: I have confirmed that the issue is related to a USB 3.0 extension cable, and see my update to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through some more tests, I confirmed that the issue is related to a USB 3.0 extension cable.

I have been using a USB extension cable to organize the space on my table, and the USB Ethernet adapter works OK when running Windows 10. However, after upgrading to Windows 11, I started having the described disconnecting issue.

- If I unplug the adapter from the extension cable and connect it to the laptop directly, the issue disappears, but
- if I connect it to the extension cable, the issue returns. Moreover, connecting another device through the cable, e.g. a USB 2.0 printer, will get the same disconnecting issue.

This update provides a temporary workaround and more information to narrow the root cause to a smaller area. But, it is not an elegant solution for the long term.

Comment: Nice work! Feel free to check this off as the answer in a day or so. Self-solved questions are very much welcome here.